# Connection refused for chrome when running scripts using selenium webserver and ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have created a ruby file which has a global variable:
DRIVER = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

Then I created global methods:

```
def setup
  @driver=DRIVER
  @base_url = "http://www.google.com/"
  @accept_next_alert = true
  @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
  @verification_errors = []
end

def teardown
  @driver=DRIVER
  @driver.quit
  assert_equal [], @verification_errors
end
```

When I try to use it in my scripts, it displays: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2).

The above code works fine for safari and firefox. Any idea why the error is displayed?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the `selenium-webdriver` gem? The current version is `2.40.0`.

Comment: Also, what version of Chrome?

Comment: Chrome: Version 33.0.1750.117

Comment: Justin, I was using selenium-webdriver-2.35.1.gem but now I updated it to 2.40.0 but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue fixed by using the below line
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors ]